# Windows: Have Jupyter Notebook save on a drive other than the installation drive

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

My PC has HDD and SDD configuration. 
By default, the SDD is selected as the C drive and when I installed Anaconda, it was installed in the C drive. When I open the Jupyter Notebook, it shows me the available paths to download, only in C drive.
But I wanted to create the notebook (.ipynb) in D drive and store it there. It is not showing me any paths related to D drive.
How do I save my notebook in D drive?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda's installer hard-codes many path names. This has impacted me many times. On a Unix box you can put in place a symlink. Although windows has symlinks, it's hard to create and maintain them. Your easiest solution is to reinstall on the D drive: Python doesn't really work well with C: and D: drives, since they are different filesystems in a different namespace.

With that said, you can also hunt around and change the Jupyter Notebook config file.